# How to configure a variant for a material in MRP3 view using BAPI?

Tags: sap-erp, bapi

Which BAPI should I use in `MRP3` view of `MM02` transaction to create a configurable variant for a finished good material in SAP?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MATERIAL_SAVE_CONFIGURATION` FM like this:

1. Get configuration object for the given plant

   ```
   CALL FUNCTION 'CUXM_GET_CONFIGURATION'
     EXPORTING
       instance = ls_marc-cuobj
       werks    = ls_marc-werks
     TABLES
       t_e1cucfg = ic_e1cucfg
       t_e1cuins = ic_e1cuins
       t_e1cuval = ic_e1cuval
       t_e1cucom = ic_e1cucom
   ```

   Alternatively, you can fill parameters manually

   ```
   lt_e1cucfg-POSEX    = '4000'.
   lt_e1cucfg-CONFIG_ID = '000001'.
   lt_e1cucfg-ROOT_ID  = '00000001'.
   lt_e1cucfg-COMPLETE  = 'T'.
   lt_e1cucfg-CONSISTENT = 'T'.
   APPEND lt_e1cucfg.

   lt_e1cuins-INST_ID      = '00000001'.
   lt_e1cuins-OBJ_TYPE      = 'MARA'.
   lt_e1cuins-CLASS_TYPE    = '300'.
   lt_e1cuins-OBJ_KEY      = 'C_GLTP'.
   lt_e1cuins-QUANTITY      = '1000'.
   lt_e1cuins-QUANTITY_UNIT = 'KG'.
   lt_e1cuins-COMPLETE      = 'T'.
   lt_e1cuins-CONSISTENT    = 'T'.
   lt_e1cuins-OBJECT_GUID  = 'C_GLTP'.
   APPEND lt_e1cuins.

   gv_matnr = '000000000004002322'.
   lt_e1cuval-inst_id = '00000001'.
   lt_e1cuval-valcode = '1'.
   lt_e1cuval-charc = 'SHOT_PEENING_Y_N'.
   lt_e1cuval-value = 'N'.
   APPEND lt_e1cuval.

   lt_e1cuval-charc = 'BENDING_Y_N'.
   lt_e1cuval-value = 'N'.
   APPEND lt_e1cuval.

   lt_e1cuval-charc = 'LENGTH_MIN_DISCRIMINATING_MM'.
   lt_e1cuval-value = '5000'.
   APPEND lt_e1cuval.

   lt_e1cuval-charc = 'LENGTH_MAX_DISCRIMINATING_MM'.
   lt_e1cuval-value = '7000'.
   APPEND lt_e1cuval.
   ```
2. Use returned values as input parameters for the `MATERIAL_SAVE_CONFIGURATION`

   ```
       CALL FUNCTION 'MATERIAL_SAVE_CONFIGURATION'
        EXPORTING
          material = ls_marc-matnr
          conf_matl = ls_mara-satnr
          plant = ls_marc-werks
          conf_matl_plant = ls_mara-satnr
        TABLES
          E1CUCFG = i_e1cucfg
          E1CUINS = i_e1cuins
          E1CUVAL = i_e1cuval
          E1CUCOM = i_e1cucom
          e1cucfg_w = ic_e1cucfg
          e1cuins_w = ic_e1cuins
          e1cuval_w = i_e1cuval
          e1cucom_w = ic_e1cucom
   ```

Comment: Suncatcher, those functions are not remotely-enabled. Once I remotely enable them I could call them , you think?

Comment: @ValK, the first one can be replaced by the manual filling (updated the answer accordingly), and `MATERIAL_SAVE_CONFIGURATION` is perfectly remote-enabled. If this is not the case on your system, read note [736873](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/736873) and check if it's implemented in your system.